# ASP.Net Web page in C# , Facebook LIKE & Comment button needed

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, windows, winforms

Hi i am creating a simple website in ASP.net & C#.
Suppose my website name is 'XYZ', & on FACEBOOK same name page i.e. 'XYZ'.
So how could i show facebook 'Like' button n when i click it on website, It actually likes on FB..
same when I comment on webpage that comment automatically added to facebook.

Thanks Advance, Uegent Help Needed...

Comment: Did you read Facebook's extensive documentation?

Comment: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/

Comment: this question has nothing to do with winforms.

Answer (score 1):

for likes code you can visit http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like/
and for comments http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/comments/

**Sample fb like iframe code place this on your website inside body and also change the href value to your facebook page**

```
<iframe src="//www.facebook.com/plugins/like.php?href=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.facebook.com%2Fxyz&amp;send=false&amp;layout=standard&amp;width=450&amp;show_faces=true&amp;action=like&amp;colorscheme=light&amp;font&amp;height=80" scrolling="no" frameborder="0" style="border:none; overflow:hidden; width:450px; height:80px;" allowTransparency="true"></iframe>
```